# Python - float arithmetic as string

Tags: python, string

I am working with Python and have two strings which contain float style values, For example:

```
a = '0.0000001'
b = '0.0003599'
```

I am looking for a solution to simply add or subtract the two values together to a new string, keeping the decimal precision intact. I have tried converting them to a float and using a + b etc but this seems to be inconsistent.

So the resulting string in this example would be string

```
c = '0.0003600'
```

I've been over a number of examples/methods and not quite found the answer. Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the `decimal` module?

Comment: "but this seems to be inconsistent." can you elaborate on that? What are you seeing exactly, and what is the problem? What would the solution give you?

Comment: Are you saying you want the result to be `'0.0003600'` rather than `'0.00036'`? And you don't know ahead of time how many decimals will be required?

Comment: thats correct. To be more precise i am looking, in this example, to add A to B, so 0.0003600 + 0.0000001. So the decimal precision would keep the legnth of B. when using floats the precision gets lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `decimal` module should do what you want:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> a = '0.0000001'
>>> b = '0.0003599'
>>> Decimal(a)+Decimal(b)
Decimal('0.0003600')
```

Comment: `*` imports are discouraged. `from decimal import Decimal` should be sufficient. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html

Answer (score 1):

[`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) library could do arbitrary precision float arithmetic:

```
>>> from mpmath import mpf
>>> a = mpf('0.0003599')
>>> b = mpf('0.0000001')
>>> print(a + b)
0.00036
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to a `float` is fine for all cases I can think of:

```
>>> str(sum(float(i) for i in (a, b)))
'0.00036'
>>> str(sum(map(float, (a, b))))
'0.00036'
>>> str(float(a) + float(b))
'0.00036'
```